# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for not showing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 app that includes these two models: `costproject` and `costestimate`.

The `costproject` model contains:

```
has_many :costestimates
accepts_nested_attributes_for :costestimates
```

The `costestimate` records are automatically created for each `costproject` - so they are always present.

I'm trying to create a form to update all of the `costestimate` records for a particular `costproject`

My form contains:

```
<%= form_for @costproject do |f| %>
...
<% f.fields_for :costestimates do |builder| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= builder.number_field :amount %></td>
     <td><%= builder.text_area :notes, :rows => 3 %></td>
   </tr>
...
```

But, none of the `costestimate` records show up in the form.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what happens if you change `f.fields_for...` to the variant `@costproject.costestimates.each do |builder|`? Also, did you add `:costestimates_attributes` to the `attr_accessor` in your Costproject model?

Comment: I thought the `f.fields_for...` was required for what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's the simple things:

Changed

```
<% f.fields_for :costestimates do |builder| %>
```

To

```
<%= f.fields_for :costestimates do |builder| %>
```

I was missing the `=`